# Two bowlers share an over - credit for Maiden?

Tags: cricket

If two bowlers bowl in an over, due to an injury to the first bowler, and the over is a Maiden Over, which bowler gets the credit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The over shall go down in the books as a Maiden Over, but it will not be credited to either of the bowlers.**

As neither of the bowlers have actually completed said over (ie one bowler will be on 12.4 overs, and the other 15.2, for example), from a statisticians point of view, you can't award a bowler a Maiden for an over they have not fully completed.

---

This is not really a matter of rules / laws, more statistics, so finding any formal documentation to confirm this has been a bit difficult, however we can take a look at an example from cricinfo:

[Match - Australia v South Africa, Perth, 3rd-7th November 2016](https://www.espncricinfo.com/series/10615/scorecard/1000851/australia-vs-south-africa-1st-test-sa-tour-of-australia-2016-17)*

In this particular match, in the 38th over of Australia's first innings, Dale Steyn cannot complete his over due to injuring his shoulder, and is replaced by Keshav Maharaj. Before the 38th over, both bowlers stats were as follows:

| Bowler | Overs | Maidens | Runs | Wickets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D Steyn | 12 | 3 | 51 | 1 |
| K Maharaj | 2 | 0 | 16 | 0 |

And after the 38th Over - which was a Maiden:

| Bowler | Overs | Maidens | Runs | Wickets |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| D Steyn | 12.4 | 3 | 51 | 1 |
| K Maharaj | 2.2 | 0 | 16 | 0 |

Neither of them were credited with the Maiden.

<sub>* Found from a quick google of the same question - credit for the Match has to go to this [Quora post](https://www.quora.com/If-a-bowler-bowls-4-balls-and-leaves-and-another-bowler-completes-the-over-and-no-runs-are-given-away-is-it-taken-as-a-maiden)</sub>